# Keep session name during automatic refresh, but not forever

Tags: php, session, refresh, destroy

I know this has been discussed a lot, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem:

I have a password that is passed to new php file with a form as follows:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" />
</form>
```

On the test.php file I create a session, then get the password with POST as follows:

```
session_name('first'); 
session_start('first');

if (isset($_SESSION['pass_s'])) 
{
   $_SESSION['pass_s'] = $_SESSION['pass_s'];
} else 
{
   $_SESSION['pass_s'] = $_POST['password'];
}  
$pass = $_SESSION['pass_s'];
```

But I also refresh this page with the following:

```
 $page = "test.php";
 $sec = 60;
 header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

The problem is, that the session stays set no matter what, so on new login the old session is started. I am stuck between naming my sessions and refreshing my page. 
I can't destroy sessions because of the refresh, but I also can't keep the session. I believe i is kept in the cookies.

I basically need to destroy a session on exit of page, but not while the refresh is running on the page?

Comment: Why do you refresh the page? There may be a better way to accomplish what you want without the refresh.

Comment: Hi, the password is used to retrieve data from a database. The data is alam reports from our server, we want the webpage to appear as real-time and display the alarms

Comment: You should use AJAX with a javascript timeout for that, not constant automatic refreshes. An automatically refreshing page is a terrible user experience. "Hey, WTF, I was just about to click something and the page refreshed for no reason!"

Comment: I know this is old tread, AJAX can work with databases through a webservice, you can point AJAX with some arguments or none to a pre-existing php script that queries a database or other data storage tecnology after fetching the require data you can send it back as json then AJAX will have it as a response and you will be able to modify the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. No sessions needed. Here is what you do:

```
if ($_POST["password"] != "")
{
    $passb = $_POST["password"];
    $userb = $_POST["username"];

}
else
{
    $userb = $_GET["userb"];
    $passb = $_GET["passb"];

}

$urllink = "60;url=thisPage.php?userb=".$userb."&passb=".$passb;
```

then insert

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT=<?php echo $urllink?>>
```

this will refresh every 60 seconds

Basically you check if the variables is posted. then you put it in a link and send it to yourself on refresh. This still needs better security but works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

First, session_start hasn't args as u can see in: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php

Second, php sessions have lifetime. The default in the php.ini for the session.gc_maxlifetime directive (the "gc" is for garbage collection) is 1440 seconds or 24 minutes. See the Session Runtime Configuation page in the manual.

Then, if u wanna close ur session just use session_destroy or unset($_SESSION['pass_s'])

Comment: Okay, but I still want to refresh the page or at least recall my sql queries very 60seconds, I can't call SQL queries from Javascript, so AJAX doesn't work.

I can't put session_destroy() cause then I loose the password that was sent to the page

Comment: Cause with AJAX, you have to do everything in javascript, and you can't call sql queries in JS

Comment: Has anybody got an idea on how to do this? I know a automatic refresh sounds funny, but not if the client requires it...

Comment: Well I figured it out. No sessions needed. Here is what you do:

if ($_POST["password"] != "")
{
 $passb = $_POST["password"];
 $userb = $_POST["username"];

}
else
{
 $userb = $_GET["userb"];
 $passb = $_GET["passb"];

}


$urllink = "60;url=thisPage.php?userb=".$userb."&passb=".$passb."&selectb=".$selectb;

then insert 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT=<?php echo $urllink?>>

Comment: u can do an AJAX to script.php and use sql in script.php.